# Event handler being triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I add event handlers to all my inputs in a sudoku game using `addEventListener`.
Every time that I write a number inside an input handler is running 3 times, why?
I want it to run only once for each element.
How can I do that?

```
// passing the board game
function addListener(game) {
  counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
      //add evenListener to all the input filds
      document.querySelectorAll('input')[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
          //save the innerHtml of the value that we write
          let inputInnerHTML = Number(this.value);
          //save the id of the input that we write in
          let index = this.id;
          checkIfCorrect(inputInnerHTML, index, game)
      })
  };
}

function checkIfCorrect(inputInnerHTML, index, game) {
  for (let i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
      //if the original number is the same, the number will be black
      if (inputInnerHTML === 0) {
          // if the input is erased remove the classes
          document.getElementById(index).classList.remove('wrong');
          document.getElementById(index).classList.remove('correct');
      }
      if (game[i] === inputInnerHTML) {
          document.getElementById(index).classList.add('correct');
          break;
      } else if (game[i] !== inputInnerHTML && inputInnerHTML !== 0) {
          //if the number is not the same, the number will be red
          //and if we did not erase the number add red and count
          document.getElementById(index).classList.add('wrong');
          counter++
          if (counter === 1) {
              document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = 'Mistakes: 1/3'; 
          }
          if (counter === 2) {
              document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = 'Mistakes: 2/3'; 
          }
          if (counter === 3) {
              //go to you lose
              document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = 'Mistakes: 3/3';
              youLose();  
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you adding an event listner multiple times ( you are adding event listner at same input multiple times) .
Can you give more information?

Comment: i have the full code on github, https://github.com/Vica-lish/sudoku

Comment: I think that you are initalizing the addListeners every time you select a difficultyButton. So  If you make several clicks, you'll be adding this events. You can try to removeEventListener, and then addEventListener

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Javascript conditional click event running multiple times](/q/47275159/90527)", "[click() firing multiple times](/q/3460562/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `addEventListener` every time you select a `difficultyButton`. This means that each time you click a button, you'll be adding an eventListener.

Fix this by calling [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), before calling `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `checkIfCorrect function`, after it is detected correct or not it doesn't stop and keep searching creating confusion.

By adding the break to the else if we block the search if the error has already been detected and notified.

```
function checkIfCorrect(inputInnerHTML, index, game) {
        for (let i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
            //if the original number is the same, the number will be black
            if (inputInnerHTML === 0) {
                // if the input is erased remove the classes
                document.getElementById(index).classList.remove('wrong');
                document.getElementById(index).classList.remove('correct');
            }
            if (game[i] === inputInnerHTML) {
                document.getElementById(index).classList.add('correct');
                break;
            } else if (game[i] !== inputInnerHTML && inputInnerHTML !== 0) {
                //if the number is not the same, the number will be red
                //and if we did not erase the number add red and count
                document.getElementById(index).classList.add('wrong');
                counter++
                if (counter === 1) {
                    document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = 'Mistakes: 1/3';
                }
                if (counter === 2) {
                    document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = 'Mistakes: 2/3';
                }
                if (counter === 3) {
                    //go to you lose
                    document.getElementById('mistakes').innerHTML = 'Mistakes: 3/3';
                    youLose();
                }
                break; // FIX
            }
        }
    }
```